# Getting Exception when trying to export data form datagrid to excel in silverlight 4.0

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-4.0, silverlight-oob

Am using silverlight 4.0  ,here am trying to export the data from datagrid to excel and getting exception as **This operation is not supported in the current context for excel** when running in the browser but it works in OOB(out of browser) window.Here my code snippet is

```
dynamic excel = AutomationFactory.CreateObject("Excel.Application");
```

can anyone help for this or any suggesion to export the data.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `AutomationFactory` is only available in a OOB app with Elevated Trust.  You cannot use it in browser.

Suggested Reading:  [Trusted Applications](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee721083%28v=VS.95%29.aspx)